# How to changed color of visited button text?

Tags: html, css, button, visited

So I have code like

```
<button id="create_btn" class="btn" type="button" title="List Available Games">List Games</button>
```

and I want to have the color always be white, even after visited. My CSS looks like:

```
.btn {
    border-radius: 0px; 
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
}
.btn:hover { 
    color: white; 
}
#create_btn {
    background-color: firebrick; 
    width: 120px;
    height: 42px;
}
```

but I don't know how to make the color stay white when I click it, even though it currently does nothing (in the application, it's going to create or list the games on a table below without refreshing, so what should I do? I tried `.btn:visited { color: white;}` but that doesn't work, also tried adding `<a></a>` around it and changing the `a:visited` but the text still is black when clicked.

I'm not even sure if it's the 'visited' concept, because when I click the button, I haven't added the JS functionality for it to do anything yet, so it just sits there loading until I click somewhere else. While it's 'loading' after clicked, it's black, and I'd like it to stay white.

Comment: Specificity. You have a rule for an element's ID which overwrites the rule for its class, that's declared before. [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) / [Specifics on CSS Specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Comment: so just move the #create_btn to be declared before .btn in the css?

Comment: By the way, your code is working just as it is. I can see only white text, no matter what. Maybe you forgot to set the button original colour somewhere before copying + pasting the code here?

Comment: its very strange though because in fiddle it works fine, yet on my page in the browser locally it goes black like its waiting for something.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your CSS gets overwritten. Please use FireBug (http://getfirebug.com/enable) and check the class/id for overrides

https://jsfiddle.net/z7h0kc79/ - seems fine.

```
<button id="create_btn" class="btn" type="button" title="List Available Games">List Games</button>


.btn {
border-radius: 0px; 
color: white;
display: inline-block;
}

.btn:hover { color: white; }
#create_btn {
background-color: firebrick; 
width: 120px;
height: 42px;
}
```

Comment: yea its strange because that's the same code I have, nothing different. yet running on fiddle it works. maybe its something to do with the page as a whole, like the button on my page makes my cursor go to the hand (like it's a link) when hovering, then I click and the text goes black until i click somewhere else)

Answer (score -1):

You've got your CSS written to style the button as well as when you hover on the button. What you're missing is the CSS styling for visited. This can be added to your CSS stylesheet:

.btn:visited {   }

Put your "background-color" (which will color the entire button). Remember that "color" only ever applies to text.

You can also changed the visited button to an image after its been visited. Drawing the image in CSS is fairly simple.  You end up with .btn:visited {background-image:   }

Comment: I said that I tried the .btn.visited{color:white;} but it doesn't do anything. it's strange that after clicking somewhere else on the page, it goes back to white, it only goes black after I click it (like it's loading)

Comment: Did you try {background-color:white} or {color:white}?